# Escaping an included jsp file

Tags: jsp, include, escaping

I'm working with a JSP file which includes others, but as it's used for an AJAX response the included files need to be escaped. My initial attempt was this:

```
<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(<%@include file="file.jsp"%>)%>
```

which gives this error:

```
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
```

This is clearly incorrect, but should show what I'm trying to do. Is there anyway accomplish what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was solved by replacing all double-quotes with single-quotes, removing newlines, and by chance any parts with both double- and single-quotes was removed so didn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it should be JS-escaped? It shouldn't. If you want to send HTML back, you send HTML back. The fact that it's an AJAX request doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's sent back as JSON, and if quotes are included in the JSP included pages it doesn't work :(

Comment: You're using a JSP to generate JSON? Why? This should be done using a JSON marshaller or API, in Java, in a servlet or action of your preferred MVC framework.

Comment: The main reason is to re-use bits of JSP, as otherwise I'd have almost the same thing twice.